# If P = NP, would dynamic programming be obsolete?

Tags: complexity-theory, dynamic-programming

I know that dynamic programming is used to solve in "pseudo-polynomial time" some NP problems, like the knapsack. If P = NP, would it mean that every problem that we solve with dynamic programming would have a more efficient (polynomial) way to solve? Or are there problems that even if P = NP, we would still use dynamic programming

Comment: dynamic programming is only a "trick" to solve complex problems.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not. P = NP doesn't imply that problems that can be solved with dynamic programming can be solved easier or quicker with another algorithm.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Does that mean that only some problems that can be solved with dynamic programming would have a quicker algorithm? Doesn't by definition, if P = NP, the knapsack problem would have a polynomial time algorithm, which must be more efficient than the usual dynamic programming approach?

Comment: @user14789259 Complexity analysis ignores coefficients. But actual performance can sometimes be dominated by this.